# Does phpMyAdmin have a query syntax check feature?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, phpmyadmin, syntax-checking

Having previously used **Microsoft's SQL Management Studio**, I often used the query syntax check feature, pretty handy especially in a production environment.

- Is there a similar feature in **phpMyAdmin** ?
- If not, is there a way to validate the proper syntax of an SQL script without executing it ?

Any help or link to a related would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently phpMyAdmin give some [error icons](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/db_sql.php?db=check&token=af59a89f0e9593ba60487cc67f4c783a) (red crosses) when you type invalid queries.

[image]
There are many tools available online, but below are the two which I used most of the times

1. [MySQL Syntax Check](http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/)
2. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) A tool for easy online testing and sharing of database problems and their solutions

Comment: The phpMyAdmin i'm using is running on version 4.0.10.10 which does not come with this dynamic query checking (the lattest stable version to this day is 4.5).
It seems i'll have to use online tools... Thanks for your help !